# Any easy way to get started with web apps using Pharo 3.0?

Tags: pharo, seaside

From my web searching, I see that there is pharo 3, a new version just a couple of months old, and that seaside and the other few web frameworks I can see referenced about all say that they work with pharo 2, if it all.   What is the happy path for starting on web programs with pharo now?

Answer (score 2):

Seaside works just fine in Pharo 3, as you can see from the [nightly builds](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/Seaside/). Just follow the installation instructions at [Seaside in Pharo](http://seaside.st/download/pharo)

Comment: ... or even simpler, open configuration browser (in tools menu), look for Seaside3 and hit "Install stable version" :)